# Shadows on emission shader

Tags: shadows

Hi i have shadows after rendering on emission shader but it doesnt appear in rendered view (see the screenshot).

I tried lot of different settings for the render, on the mesh itself... i really dont find whats wrong.....

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more info like screenshots of your modifier stack. Looks like the result of different modifier settings for viewport display and rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it there was a mesh behind i forgot to delete....  waste of time!